# Nginx two virtual Hosts with Subdomains always directs to default_server

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have the following setup:

- Nginx with two virtual hosts
- two subdomains: sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com

`sub1.domain.com` is working fine. If I enter `sub2.domain.com` the browser returns a 403. I've set the directories configured for both domains to be owned by `www-data` (`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/`).

A look at the error logs reveals that `/var/log/nginx/sub2.domain.com/error.log` is empty whereas `/var/log/nginx/sub1.domain.com/error.log` contains

```
2018/03/09 11:29:00 [error] 19024#0: *13009 directory index of "/var/www/sub1.domain.com" is forbidden, client: ip, server: sub1.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "my-host"
```

Does anyone know why the server includes `sub1.domain.com` even if I've entered `sub2.domain.com` in the browser?!

I think the problem might be, that `sub2.domain.com` always seems to execute the config of `sub1.domain.com` (which is the `default_server`). According to the nginx docs:

> If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default server for this port.

Nginx config for sub1.domain.com

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/sub1.domain.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name sub1.domain.com;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/sub1.domain.com/access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/sub1.domain.com/error.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param AUTH_SECRET "my-secret";
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Nginx config for sub2.domain.com

```
upstream backend{
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/sub2.domain.com/access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/sub2.domain.com/error.log;

        root    /var/www/sub2.domain.com;

        server_name sub2.domain.com;

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        # route /api requests to backend
        location /api/v1 {
                proxy_pass              http://backend;
                proxy_http_version      1.1;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade        $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection     "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host           $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Scheme       $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy  true;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
}
```

I have followed the tutorial here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts and set up the sym links. So `/etc/nginx/sites-available` contains the config and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` contains the sym links on those configs.

Also note, that `sub1.domain.com` serves a php backend whereas `sub2.domain.com` should serve some static content (single page application) and direct the api requests to a Node.js backend.

Edit:

```
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

My `nginx.conf` file contains `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`. So the configurations, that I've posted above, should be included. At least `nginx -t` throws an error if one of the configs has an error.

Edit 2: tl;dr (summary of comments): the DNS was misconfigured. Setting the correct `A` record for both subdomains solved the problem. The nginx config is working as expected.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to display the configuration that `nginx` sees. But it looks like the second configuration file is not being read.

Comment: I've updated my post with the output of `nginx -t`.

Comment: Uppercase `T` prints out the entire configuration and will identify if your second `server` block is included.

Comment: Ah I didn'tt know this. Thought it was a typo. :) Unfortunately the installed nginx version does not support this flag. Right now I'm not sure if we can update the system to a later version. I'll check this.

Comment: Looking again at the error message, the fragment `host: "my-host"` specifies which `server_name` was being requested. Does this match the `server_name` of the second `server` block?

Comment: `my-host` is logged as `the-v-servers-domain.com`. So neither the subdomain nor the domain itself is part of it. Note that I'm using a virtual server and the two sub domains are configured to forward to the virtual server's address. Now that I'm reading this the problem might lie here?!

Comment: What exactly you are using to make the HTTP request to the server? What is the exact URL you are trying to access? Are the domain DNS records configured properly?

Comment: I've tested with the URL `http://sub2.domain.com` in the browser aswell as Postman. Both return the 403. Right now, I don't have access to the DNS settings. I'll ask the guy, who has. Just for my understanding (I don't have much experience with this): both subdomains should have an `A` record, which points to the IP of the virtual server, right?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help. Pointing out that the DNS might be configured wrong was the right way. We set the correct `A` record and now it seems to work properly